# Проговаривание текста во время вызова

Tags: android

Можно ли во время звонка программно зачитать текст собеседнику?

То есть, создать как бы телефонного бота на андроид.

Comment: Вообще такое возможно с ROOT правами, это даст вам возможность напрямую посылать на микрофон, точнее, минуя микрофон напрямую посылать звук, будто вы сами говорили, на процессор. А без рута я сильно сомневаюсь

Comment: можно. Но вам нужно решить по меньшей мере 2 вопроса: Как проиграть звук в телефонную линию, и как преобразовать текст в речь. Вот и задайте 2 вопроса. Предварительно попробуйте хоть что-то сделать сами.